# Run Grunt on many subdirectories

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a directory containing different projects:

```
top-directory/
    project1/
    project2/
    project3/
```

In most project directories is a Gruntfile. When working on a project I `cd` to its directory and run `grunt` to watch for changes.

When I need to switch to another project (sometimes just for a small change), I need to stop Grunt, `cd` to the other directory and run `grunt` again. Then repeat to go back to the original.

Is it possible to have a way run Grunt on all the project directories that contain a Gruntfile? Or on a specified list of directories? Perhaps a Gruntfile in the top directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [Grunt Hub](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub).

```
mkdir grunt-hub && cd grunt-hub
npm install grunt-hub
cp -R node_modules/grunt-hub/tasks/init/hub/* .
```

Then edit grunt-hub/Gruntfile.js to point to the directories of interest or keep the default `'../*/Gruntfile.js'`.

You may also want to remove `jshint` from the task list, and allow the other Gruntfiles to run their own checks, and avoid being notified about JS Hint suggestions for every single file, which may be a large number.

Answer (score 1):

I think **grunt-subgrunt** can help you: https://github.com/tusbar/grunt-subgrunt

With it you will be able to start tasks into a GruntFile located into a sub directory

So you created a grunt file on top directory and configure a list of tasks to call into your sub GruntFile

**EDIT**: If you only want to watch files changes, you can also use **grunt-watch** on the top directory and watch for changes into your sub-directories and start a specific task with or without **grunt-subgrunt**.